# What is the use of weight and style property when declaring custom fonts in pubspec?

Tags: flutter, fonts, pubspec

To understand my question, we need to follow the example below which from the [official flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts#2-declare-the-font-in-the-pubspec):

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

As you know this is how we declare font in Flutter and we know that we have `Raleway-Regular.ttf`, `Raleway-Italic.ttf`, `RobotoMono-Regular.ttf` and `RobotoMono-Bold.ttf` inside the `fonts` directory at the root of our project.

So my question is why do we need to set the `weight` property of the `RobotoMono-Bold.ttf` to `700`, when by default `RobotoMono-Bold.ttf` has `FontWeight.w700`

The documentation quotes

> Note that defining the weight property does not override the actual weight of the font. You would not be able to access RobotoMono-Bold with FontWeight.w100, even if its weight was set to 100.

As per the documentation if **defining the weight property does not override the actual weight of the font**, then why the `weight` property exist? Same goes for the `style` property as well.